# MySql: update row that requires some logic processing

Tags: mysql

Given the following table:

```
id    | company   | names | group
-------------------------------------
0     |     1     | John  |  1
1     |     1     | Doe   |  null //populate with preceding group number (i.e. 1) 
2     |     1     | Yo    |  null //populate with preceding group number (i.e. 1) 
3     |     1     | Zoe   |  null //populate with preceding group number (i.e. 1) 
4     |     1     | Jack  |  2
5     |     1     | Doe   |  null //populate with preceding group number (i.e. 2) 
6     |     1     | Yo    |  null //populate with preceding group number (i.e. 2)
```

May I know how i can update only the null values to its preceding group number via sql statements? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tablename t1
  JOIN (
    SELECT ID, @s:=IF(`group` IS NULL, @s, `group`) `group`
      FROM (SELECT * FROM tablename  ORDER BY ID) r,
    (SELECT @s:=NULL) t
  ) t2
  ON t1.ID = t2.ID
SET t1.`group`= t2.`group`
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62cf4/1)**

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain what happens in the JOIN ( ... )? I am unfamiliar with @s:=IF .... and (SELECT @s:=NULL). :)

Comment: @user3240644:- := is an assignment operator. Does the query works?

Comment: @user3240644:- Added a Sql Fiddle demo for reference!

Comment: @user3240644:- Is your table a temporary table in which you are executing this query?

Comment: ah yes..its a temporary table!

Comment: @user3240644:- There you go. :) `You cannot refer to a TEMPORARY table more than once in the same query`

Comment: @user3240644:- A simple alternate solution is to duplicate the tmp table or make that as a permanent table.